# Using a running total calculated column in SQL Server table variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, cumulative-sum

I have inherited a stored procedure that utilizes a table variable to store data, then updates each row with a running total calculation.  The order of the records in the table variable is very important, as we want the volume to be ordered highest to lowest (i.e. the running total will get increasingly larger as you go down the table).

My problem is, during the step where the table variable is updated, the running total seems to be calculating , but not in a way that the data in the table variable was previously sorted by (descending by highest volume)

```
DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE ([ID], [Volume], [SortValue], [RunningTotal])

--Populate table variable and order by the sort value...
INSERT INTO @TableVariable (ID, Volume, SortValue)
   SELECT   
       [ID], [Volume], ABS([Volume]) as SortValue
   FROM  
       dbo.VolumeTable  
   ORDER BY 
       SortValue DESC

--Set TotalVolume variable...
SELECT@TotalVolume = ABS(sum([Volume])) 
FROM @TableVariable

--Calculate running total, update rows in table variable...I believe this is where problem occurs?
SET @RunningTotal = 0

UPDATE @TableVariable
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + [Volume]
FROM @TableVariable

--Output...
SELECT  
    ID, Volume, SortValue, RunningTotal 
FROM    
    @TableVariable      
ORDER BY 
    SortValue DESC
```

The result is, the record that had the highest volume, that I would have expected the running total to calculate on first (thus running total = [volume]), somehow ends up much further down in the list.  The running total seems to calculate randomly

Here is what I would expect to get:

[image: Good result]

But here is what the code actually generates:

[image]

Not sure if there is a way to get the UPDATE statement to be enacted on the table variable in such a way that it is ordered by volume desc?  From what Ive read so far, it could be an issue with the sorting behavior of a table variable but not sure how to correct?  Can anyone help?

Comment: No do NOT do this. You are using what is commonly known as the quirky update method. Given that this is a table variable I already know that you are violating some of the known issues around this technique. A clustered index is required for this work correctly. Check out this article which discusses this technique. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/ Make sure you read the comments. This approach is undocumented and is highly controversial. Windows functions would suit you better here.

Comment: [Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

Comment: Your images both show volume sorted descending, and runningtotal sorted ascending, I don't see a problem...

Comment: You don't need a variable to calculate a running total. It's also a very, very limited technique - you can't query, join, filter or do anything else with that variable

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you are targeting SQL Server 2008 R2. This version is no longer supported. Newer versions have far better support for such scenarios. The speed difference (ie reduction in CPU requirements) is enough to offset the upgrade cost. You should tag the question appropriately anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Take a peek at the Window functions offered in SQL

For example

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Volume int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(100,1306489),
(125,898426),
(150,907404)

Select ID
      ,Volume
      ,RunningTotal = sum(Volume) over (Order by Volume Desc)
 From  @YourTable 
 Order By Volume Desc
```

Returns

```
ID  Volume  RunningTotal
100 1306489 1306489
150 907404  2213893
125 898426  3112319
```

**To be clear, The @YourTable is for demonstrative purposes only.  There should be no need to INSERT your actual data into a table variable.**

> **EDIT to Support 2008  (Good news is Row_Number() is supported in 2008)**

```
 Select ID
        ,Volume
        ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order by Volume Desc)
  Into  #Temp
  From  @YourTable 


 Select A.ID
       ,A.Volume
       ,RunningTotal = sum(B.Volume)
  From  #Temp A 
  Join  #Temp B on (B.RowNr<=A.RowNr)
  Group By A.ID,A.Volume
  Order By A.Volume Desc
```

Comment: This could be what i am looking for, but I keep getting an error :  Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10.  On the running total line of your code.  we are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and looking that error code up it mentions Parallel datawarehouse features not enabled??

Comment: @Spartan46236 Sorry, Sum() Over is not supported in 2008.  Give me a few minutes  to give you an alternative

Comment: Thanks for the help very much.  From the results Im seeing, this method looks to be calculating accurate, but I think the run time for the query really took a hit, likely to the point of making it unfeasible.  Any suggestions on increasing the performance?  the table Im working with is ~ half million rows.

Comment: @Spartan46236 500K should not be an issue, but sometimes CTEs can be a hit on performance.  Are you opposed to #temp tables?  see updated

Comment: Aaron Bertrand's article explains that this query does get a performance hit over other methods that use windowing functions. Also, SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. If the OP is testing against a development database, it would be better to use the same database version as in production. If the *production* database is using a 6 year old, unsupported version, it is time to upgrade. Esp. considering how a columnstore index can improve performance 100x

Answer (score 2):

GarethD provided the definitive link to the multiple ways of calculating running totals and their performance. The correct one is both the simplest and fastest, *300 times* faster that then quirky update. That's because it can take advantage of any indexes that cover the sort column, and because it's a lot simpler.

I repeat it here to make clear how much simpler this is when the database provided the appropriate windowing functions

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    TicketCount,
    SUM(TicketCount) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM dbo.SpeedingTickets
ORDER BY [Date];
```

The `SUM` line means: Sum all ticket counts over  all (UNBOUNDED) the rows that came before (PRECEDING) the current one if they were ordered by date

That ends up being 300 times faster than the quirky update.

The equivalent query for `VolumeTable` would be:

```
SELECT   
   ID, 
   Volume, 
   ABS(Volume) as SortValue,
   SUM(Volume) OVER (ORDER BY ABS(Volume) DESC RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM  
   VolumeTable
ORDER BY ABS(Volume) DESC
```

Note that this will be a lot faster if there is an index on the sort column (Volume), and ABS isn't used. Applying any function on a column means that the optimizer can't use any indexes that cover it, because the actual sort value is different than the one stored in the index.

If the table is very large and performance suffers, you could create a computed column and create an index on it